# Using GdkFrameClock to synchronize a GtkDrawingArea with the screen refresh rate

Tags: gtk, screen, gtk3, gdk, vsync

### Background

I want to synchronize the updating of a widget to the screen refresh rate using `GdkFrameClock`. This is for visual stimulation response measurements off of an LCD screen (and therefore requiring as-close-to-exact frame synchronization as possible for purity of the signal).

I've read the documentation for the class, but it's limited in scope; I'm missing some overarching understanding of GdkFrameClock's place in the GTK world. Perusing the demos in the GTK source tree on GitHub has been fruitless for me.

### Question

Assuming that I *can*, how do I use `GdkFrameClock` to synchronize the updating of the screen representation of a `GtkDrawingArea` (assume Cairo) to the screen refresh rate?

If I *can't*, what's the purpose of `GdkFrameClock`?

Comment: These two blog posts helped me getting an *overarching understanding* of GdkFrameClock: [The Modern Gtk Drawing Model](https://blogs.gnome.org/alexl/2013/11/04/the-modern-gtk-drawing-model/) and [Drawing in Gtk](https://blog.gtk.org/2016/06/15/drawing-in-gtk/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't used `GdkFrameClock` in anger, just for a little bit of testing, but the following seems quite easy and works for me:

1. Call `gtk_widget_add_tick_callback()`, passing the function you want to run on each refresh
2. Roughly 60 times a second (or as appropriate for your system), your callback will be called
3. When you're done, call `gtk_widget_remove_tick_callback()` or return `FALSE` from your callback to stop receiving updates.

In step 2, you are passed the `GdkFrameClock` in use, so you can call `gdk_frame_clock_get_frame_time()` to get the exact frame timestamp, or use `gdk_frame_clock_get_timings()` and the `GdkFrameTimings` API to do more interesting things.

The following Vala code (easily convertible to D I'm sure :-)) shows this in action:

```
private static bool on_frame_tick(Gtk.Widget widget, Gdk.FrameClock frame_clock)
{
    print("Got frame tick with timestamp %lld\n", frame_clock.get_frame_time());

    return true; // Keep going
}

void main(string[] args)
{
    Gtk.init(ref args);

    var w = new Gtk.Window(Gtk.WindowType.TOPLEVEL);
    w.add_tick_callback(on_frame_tick, null);
    w.show_all();

    Gtk.main();
}
```

Note that as per [the docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.10/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-add-tick-callback), you'll need to call `gtk_widget_queue_draw()` (or `queue_draw_area()`) in your handler get it to get GTK to actually perform the redraw. This will in turn call the `draw()` function of the widget in question.

As such, what I'd do is to save the frame timing information in my tick callback, call `queue_redraw()`, then use the saved timing info in the `draw()` implementation of my `GtkDrawingArea`.

Comment: You're stalking me! :-P Thanks.